# I only see 29 achievements for Bleed, but Steam says there's 32?

Tags: steam, achievements, bleed

As I said, I can only count 29 achievements here, but Steam is telling me there's 32 of them.  Am I missing something here, or is Steam just making a mistake?

Are there hidden achievements or something?

[image: 32? I only count 29!]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This isn't a mistake; there are three hidden achievements for Bleed on Steam.  The three of them and their requirements are as follows:

---

**Quiet Contemplation**
Awarded for standing atop the last elevator in the hall of heroes for a moment (Wryn recites poetry)

[image: Quiet Contemplation]

---

**Excessively Stylish**
Awarded for reflecting a bullet that was reflected by the Rival

[image: Excessively Stylish]

---

**S-Rank: Rival**
Awarded for defeating the rival with style rank of S (the highest)

[image: S-Rank: Rival]